# Including a "clickable" standalone tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I am wondering how I can include a clickable tikz figure generated as `standalone` and preserve the `clickable` functionality.

The following file generates a pdf that shows a popup when I click on the figure.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [domain=0:1] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I include it using either `includegraphics` or `pgfimage`, the clickable functionality is lost.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf,epsfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[page=1]{fig_test.pdf}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\pgfimage[page=1]{fig_test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm using pdfLaTeX on MikTeX to compile it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably not related: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` is very old - we are at `1.18` now.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists...

Comment: First of i don't know what clickable does here (not at pc). But if it generates clickiness like hyperlinks or similar, then that normally gets lost with other meta data when sent through includegraphics, the image will be treated as purely graphics. For hyperref there is a solution posted on the site. No idea if it would work in the case

Comment: Maybe a workaround is to use `\input` to add the code for the graph to your main document. In that case you should remove the preamble from the graph code and put `\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}` in the main document.

Comment: Thanks, daleif and Marijn. Yes, including the figure code in the main text works, but I was looking for a solution that allows me to compile them separately because I have a lot of figures to include.